# ESP32 & Telegram bot https getUpdate API - HTTPS client certificate

Tags: https, openssl, ssl-certificate, telegram-bot, esp32

I have developed a simple Telegram bot communication with my ESP32 To carry out the tests, I used a predefined certificate (I think part of ESP32 examples).

Now I would like to be able to create my own certificate.

I have tried to generate a certificate using OpenSSL but without success. Replacing the certificate used for testing with the one I generated myself always fails to connect to the telegram server with the error:

```
E (7802) esp-tls-mbedtls: mbedtls_ssl_handshake returned -0x2700
I (7802) esp-tls-mbedtls: Failed to verify peer certificate!
E (7812) esp-tls: Failed to open new connection
E (7812) transport_base: Failed to open a new connection
E (7822) HTTP_CLIENT: Connection failed, sock < 0`
```

How can I generate a certificate to be used for the HTTPS connection to the Telegram server?